# how to use sed command in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I had written a shell script with the following commands :

```
if [[ $(echo $FILE_NAME | awk -F"_" '{print $3}') == "IMAGE" ]];
    then
echo "in if of f_name"
     F_NAME=`echo $FILE_NAME | sed 's/IMAGE/UCM/'`
echo $F_NAME 
    else
echo "in else of f_name"
    F_NAME=`echo $FILE_NAME | sed 's/FUSION_CONFIGURATION_1/UCM/'`
    fi
```

This searched for the FILENAME which was the parameter and then go into this if else and then give the result. How can this LOGIC be used in the batch file ?

This is giving an internal or external error in batch file

Comment: Because none of the syntax is even remotely close for commands you can run in a batch file.  If you want to know the syntax for a command you do the same thing you would at bash prompt and get help for the command. In this case: `IF /?`  If you want to capture the output of a command in a variable you would then use the `FOR /F` command.

Comment: Your *"code"* looks like a `bash` script for Linux/Unix rather than a Windows BATCH file. I think you should maybe remove the `batch-file` tag and apply the `bash` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my try to translate/interpret your bash code to batch.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set FILE_NAME=one_two_IMAGE_four
:: Set FILE_NAME=one_two_FUSION_CONFIGURATION_1_four

:: This replaces your awk
For /f "tokens=3 Delims=_" %%A in (
 'echo:%File_Name%'
) Do Set Token3=%%A

:: Variable content is refered to by enclosing the var name in %
:: DelayedExpansion is neccessary because inside a (code block)
:: You have to use the exclamation mark instead of the percent then
If "%Token3%"=="IMAGE" (
  Set F_NAME=!FILE_NAME:IMAGE=UCM!
) Else (
  Set F_NAME=!FILE_NAME:FUSION_CONFIGURATION_1=UCM!
)
Echo FILE_NAME=%FILE_NAME%
Echo Token3   =%Token3%
Echo F_NAME   =%F_NAME%
```

The output

```
FILE_NAME=one_two_IMAGE_four
Token3   =IMAGE
F_NAME   =one_two_UCM_four

FILE_NAME=one_two_FUSION_CONFIGURATION_1_four
Token3   =FUSION
F_NAME   =one_two_UCM_four
```

**EDIT**
To renove the extension .zip from a string each of these lines will do:

```
Set F_NAME=%F_NAME:.zip=%
For %%A in ("%F_NAME%") Do Set F_NAME=%%~nA
Set F_NAME=%F_NAME:~0,-4%
```

Comment: did you include the line with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` ?

Comment: i want to remove .zip from the F_NAME right now my filename is like one_two_IMAGE_four.zip . I want my output like one_two_IMAGE_four - Is this possible ?

Comment: Appended that info to my answer.

Comment: got the error The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~nA

Comment: Worked ! Thanks  for the response and help ! :)